# Help with a C# linq query on entity framework objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a Call object in Entity Framework representing a telephone call.

Can somebody help me out with a linq query?

I need to return the top 40 numbers dialed between a date range, including the number of times the number was dialed

Thanks

Comment: Post some code, we love code...mmmmm...code..aaargggghh (drool..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
var query = (from call in db.PhoneCalls
             where call.Date >= minDate && call.Date <= maxDate
             group call by call.Number into g
             orderby g.Count() descending
             select new { Number = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
            .Take(40);
```

That's just a guess based on what you've told us though...